# React-native set number to string by locale

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, locale

I have a number, if I use the amount.toFixed() I get this string "100.00". I want the result to be consistent with the locale.

if locale is Italian the result is 100,00 ,
if locale is English the result is 100.00

what can I use?

```
amount.toFixed(2)
```

I use react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use directly the javascript built-in method 
[Intl​.Number​Format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). There are many useful properties.

To format your number, you can use the properties `maximumSignificantDigits`, `minimumSignificantDigits`, `maximumFractionDigits`, `minimumFractionDigits` and `minimumIntegerDigits`.

Here is a working fiddle:

```js
var number = "123456.78"; // string 

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'decimal'}).format(number));

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'decimal', maximumSignificantDigits:7 }).format(number));
```

Comment: My issue is that I need to pull the locale dynamically, and Apple doesn't appear to give me a usable value.  E.g. I'm testing Argentina locale and Apple returns en-AR which is not a valid value for Intl.NumberFormat.

Comment: @LukeWilliams have you tried to use `react-native-device-info`? They provide a function to get the locale.

Comment: Here's the solution I ended up with, to both parse and write out locale-specific number strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243866/152711

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built-in function for this, Intl.NumberFormat:

```
const updateNr = (val: any) => {
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("it-IT");         
updateValue(formatter.format(val.replace(/,/g, "")));   //Remove ',' to format number again
};
```

Or you can use the [react-number-format plugin](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) if you are using React.

Comment: I use react-native.. but react-number-format can't help me because it use "." instead ","
What can i do?

Comment: What about the javascript code above, did you try that?

Comment: No need to. Did you check what Intl.NumberFormat does? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat